# How to cause the confirm alert before logout

Tags: javascript, php

I want to popup the confirm alert message *before* I logout of my account. But it doesn't popup and I am not sure whether i put the echo at the right line.

```
<?php
session_start();
session_destroy();
echo "<script> window.confirm('Are you sure to logout?');</script>";
header("location:../app/masuk.php"); 
//to redirect back to "index.php" after logging out
exit();
?>
```

Comment: session_start();
session_destroy(); ? This honestly looks very wrong. in the LOGOUT you CREATE a session and destroy it after?? and AFTER youj destroyed a session you are asking him if he wants to logout?
Another thing is, this is not possible like u wanted because PHP is run BEFORE javascript

Comment: IMPOSSIBLE...clientside code does not run on the server.

Comment: You can't mix script and PHP like that.  The confirm needed to happen **before** this page is loaded - when this page is loaded, all of the php processes before any script is run, which is why you don't see the confirm alert.

Answer (score 9):

You have to put that confirmation on the view not controller.

Let's say you have a logout button:

Html:

```
<a href="logout.php" id="logout">Logout</a>
```

Js (jquery):

```
$(function(){
    $('a#logout').click(function(){
        if(confirm('Are you sure to logout')) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    });
});
```

Php

```
<?php
// Your logout functions...
```

Answer (score 1):

You need an html link in the first place

```
<a href="logout.php" onclick=" return confirm("Are You sure you want to logout?");">Logout</a>
```

Then in your logout.php, you should have

```
<?php
session_start();
session_destroy();
header('the_page_you_wish.php');
```