# How to alert a user to click logout when he wants to leave the website?

Tags: php, jquery

How to write php code for alerting a user to click logout when he wants to leave the webpage by closing the window without clicking logout...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to cause the confirm alert before logout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23762002/how-to-cause-the-confirm-alert-before-logout)

Comment: sorry @manniL ... what you have suggested gives the result when user clicks the logout...! but i want the answer for the question of when the user closes the window without clicking logout... then how can i restrict him to click logout...

Comment: Is there a reason your user sessions need to persist across visits? If not, have them expire at the end of the session (i.e. session cookies)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check if the session is persistent, for example check if a value is set, then output the javascript code.

```
<?
if(isset($_SESSION['user'])){
    echo '
    <script type="text/javascript">
      window.onbeforeunload = function() {
          return "Did you save your stuff?"
      }';
}
?>
```

Comment: You need to properly escape your double quotes